# Python: matplotlib-venn - How do you adjust the position / move the values inside the venn diagram circles?

Tags: python, matplotlib, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

[image: How do you move the values inside the venn diagram circles?]

Here's a sample venn diagram:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
vd = venn3(subsets=(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), set_labels = ('A', 'B', 'C'))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

I figured this out by looking at the code found in this question: [Venn3: How to reposition circles and labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472578/venn3-how-to-reposition-circles-and-labels)

Specifically, this part:

```
vd.get_label_by_id("100").set_x(1.55)
```

Putting it all together (see how that 1 is all the way to the right now...):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
vd = venn3(subsets=(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), set_labels = ('A', 'B', 'C'))

#Move the numbers in the circles                                                                                                                                               
vd.get_label_by_id("100").set_x(1.55)

plt.show()
```

[image]

There appear to be a lot of other things one can set about that number. A full list of all applicable callable methods can be found by running:

```
x = venn_diagram.get_label_by_id("100")
dir(x)
```